# Multiple Users Sending Input To The Same Server Running On My Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, ssh, scripts, users, putty

I've just recently started hosting a Java based server on my Ubuntu Server.  I've been learning how to setup everything and I've been feeling pretty good about it's setup.

I currently start the server with the following `sh script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "Loading Minecraft Server..."

java -d64 -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

While setting it up, I thought it would also be pretty cool to let some other people help manage the server.

As of currently I've been SSH'ing into my server using *[PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/)*.  I `cd` to the directory and then run my `sh script` using `./run.sh`.  This all works great and I can issue commands to the server via my PuTTY client.

The server displays (and has focus?) through the PuTTY client only though.  I can't seem to send commands from the host server to the server.  How would I send commands from say the host to the Java Server that (has focus?) in the PuTTY client?

The next question is, assuming my Server had multiple users, how could I allow them to interact with the server as well (via SSH)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) program.

More specifically, [how to allow multiple users to interact with the same screen](http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/screen/Multi-User+Screen).